# How to apply hover style to disabled element in TextField component from mui version 5

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I like to add color to the disabled element when the `TextField` component is being hovered.

Here is a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-browser-qtzdmx?file=/demo.js:0-1019)

```
import * as React from "react";

import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import { AdapterDayjs } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs";
import { LocalizationProvider } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider";
import { DatePicker } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/DatePicker";

export default function BasicDatePicker() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(null);

  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
      <DatePicker
        label="Basic example"
        value={value}
        onChange={(newValue) => {
          setValue(newValue);
        }}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            disabled
            sx={{
              "& .MuiInputBase-input.Mui-disabled": {
                WebkitTextFillColor: "pink"
              },
              "& .MuiInputBase-input.Mui-disabled:hover": {
                color: "green"
              }
            }}
          />
        )}
      />
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
}
```

I see the pink text but that needs to be green when users hover it. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why it has to be `WebkitTextFillColor` not `color`.

```
          <TextField
            {...params}
            disabled
            sx={{
              "& .MuiInputBase-input.Mui-disabled": {
                WebkitTextFillColor: "pink"
              },
              "& .MuiInputBase-input.Mui-disabled:hover": {
                WebkitTextFillColor: "green"
              }
            }}
          />
```

Comment: The default MUI disabled styles use `WebkitTextFillColor` to workaround an issue in Safari: https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/23332.